# Returning a closure's variable is creating a copy instead of a reference

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm confused by this closure behavior. I've read several SO articles (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)) and MDN's documentation on closures, but haven't seen the explanation for this behavior.

In the code sample below I'm creating a closure containing a variable`cache`, a function `preload` that modifies it, and a function `report` that logs its value. It also attaches references to those to an object that is passed in.

```
'use strict';

var o = {};

(function(obj) {
    var cache = {'initialized': false};

    function preload(assets, done) {
        console.log('Preloading. Value of cache is', cache);
        cache = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
            cache[assets[i]] = assets[i];
        }
    }

    function report() {
        console.log('Cache from inside is ', cache);
    }

    function get_cache() {
        return cache;
    }

    obj.cache = cache;
    obj.preload = preload;
    obj.report = report;
} )(o);

// {initialized: false}, as expected
o.report();

// {initialized: false}, as expected
console.log('Cache from outside is ', o.cache);

// I expect this to change cache to {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
o.preload([1, 2, 3]);

// {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}, as expected
o.report();

// {initialized: false}, NOT as expected. Why?
console.log('Cache from outside is ', o.cache);
```

My expectation is based on my understanding that when the closure attaches `cache` to the provided `obj`, it is assigning a reference to the variable within the closure. But the behavior I'm seeing suggests that `obj.cache` is getting a *copy* of the closure's `cache`.

At which point is a copy of `cache` created and why?

Comment: Why are you not exposing `get_cache` but the initial value of the `cache` variable?

Comment: Because you're making a copy: `cache = {}`. Note that the only closure is the variable `cache` itself. The variable `obj.cache` is not a closure but is instead a normal reference/pointer assignment like in C or Java or other languages. As such, it makes `obj.cache` point to the same object pointed to by `cache` but not the variable `cache` itself. In other words, `obj.cache = cache` assigns the pointer to cache by value (it makes a copy of the pointer like in most programming languages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `obj.cache = cache;` in the beginning, you are making `obj.cache` points to the same object that `cache` is pointing to (This object: `{'initialized': false}`)

Then later when you call `preload`, you point the variable `cache` to another, new object: `cache = {};`. Now the `cache` variable is pointing to a brand new object, while `obj.cache` still point to the old object that was created in the beginning.

That explain why all log done on `cache` inside the closure logs new values, while logging `obj.cache` still show unchanged values. They're now pointing to 2 different objects, and changing the content of the object that `cache` is now pointing to have no effect on the original object has `obj.cache` is pointing to.

Comment: Oh! Duh! I didn't even think that `cache = {}` was reassigning cache to a new object, but now that you point it out it's very clear. I was thinking this was just emptying the object that `cache` referred to. This makes perfect sense now and my sanity is restored. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At the time your `IIFE` got executed, you have added `cache` to `obj.cache` and that was that. `obj.cache` doesn't hold a reference to the `cache` variable from your `IIFE`. But, `report` and `preload` functions are using `cache` variable from your `IIFE`, even as they are invoked outside of the scope where they have been created. As such, reference to the scope inside your `IIFE` is being preserved for `obj.preload` and `obj.report` functions (this is where closure is being observed), but not for `obj.cache`.

For more details on various situations how closure is being observed and exercised, please check out this [link](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md#you-dont-know-js-scope--closures).